# Changing site language with only javascript without server site code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My website only have 5 html page. I want to change language with javascript or jquery. How can i do that. I want to change language with one click but other page will still same language. What i must supposed to do?

Comment: Please show us what you've already tried.

Comment: Dont do anything i dont want to use asp.net or php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have very few options.

1. Have html version of your page in every language you have on your
   website with corresponding links and maybe cookies to keep track of
   your language.
2. Have all text in Javascript files and keep track of language in cookies and update text with JavaScript accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Google has a free service for this

https://translate.google.com/manager/website/

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about this service.